# automatically change connection string. hosting

Tags: asp.net, hosting

When i hosted site I need to change connection string.I have 2 connection string(for test on local computer,for hosting) Can it be possible to make the switching connection string occurs automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Add reference to add System.Configuration:-

use this to get your connection string;

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnStr"].ConnectionString;
```

place this code in your web config file;

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="ConnStr" 
       connectionString="Server=localhost; Database=Foo; Integrated Security=True" ;
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

have different connection strings in your local and hosting once,after that don't upload web config file to hosting unless you have to.